# Android support for flash

Tags: android, flash

This question is regarding Android backward hardware/OS(api level) compatibility.

I am developing Adobe Air application on Android. I know to run these applications we require Adobe AIR runtime installed on our Android devices.

But I have one question **android flash support dependent on hardware or os?** or **Is it only dependent on Adobe AIR runtime is installed on Android device or not?**

Answer (score 1):

See this link below to know about system requirements to use Adobe AIR.

[Adobe AIR 3 / Tech specs](http://www.adobe.com/products/air/tech-specs.html#mobile)

I faced some problems without reading the information at above link. So have a look to avoid doubts.

I hope it may help you.

Comment: If I have not installed AIR in my Android. Can I play flash files?

Comment: where you will play flash files ??

Comment: Suppose I am playing flash file in native application(not android flex application)...then what? Is it possible without AIR?

Comment: is it .swf file ? playing by using WebView ?

Comment: fla/swf file..can I not play it without Webview??

Comment: .fla is flash project file which creates .swf file. .swf file is like executable file which requires adobe flash run time libraries. Web browsers also playing these .swf files by taking help of adobe flash player which is installed as plugin for our browsers.

Comment: Suppose I am playing .swf file in browser(Webview) of Android version ealier than 2.2 without AIR runtime is it possible to play the file?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9133/discussion-between-yugandhar-babu-and-vishal)